# при разработке в Eclipse WindowBuilder, Eclipse виснет, нет отклика?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Работаю в **eclipse**. для более легкой разработки **GUI** установил **Eclipse WindowBuilder**, **Swing Designer** и **SWT Designer**.
когда начинаю делать какую-то форму **eclipse** очень жестко подвисает, нет отклика. 
в чем может быть проблема?
чем ВЫ пользуетесь для **GUI**?

Comment: А почему используете Swing? Ведь есть JavaFx, довольно сильная штука, которая должна заменить Swing. Для нее так же есть удобный UI генератор - Scene Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ui генераторы обычно выдают не читаемый код, причем если вы будете менять этот код потом руками - возможность редактировать через SwingDesigner будет уже не возможно. Для более-менее серьезных проектов код ui пишется руками, ui designer подходит для обучения, не более того. /imho/

Comment: Balashev плохо. я по памяти с **netbeans** правил руками, а оно так. спасибо. значит буду опять руками)